# pop up a modal window when click a link button in grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a " div " tag id is 'modal' . there is a grid in the same page. The grid shows document Details. So When i click a link buttion in grid.. then i need a modal window to pop up. My page has a master page also.. So how can i do this...when i click the link button nothing happens...

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd_review" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="DOC_ID" EnableModelValidation="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="grd_review_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    onrowcommand="grd_review_RowCommand" onrowdeleting="grd_review_RowDeleting" 
            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" 
            Height="233px">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DOC_ID" HeaderText="id" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DOC_NAME" HeaderText="Doc Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Created By" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CREATE_DATE" HeaderText="Created Date" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_file" runat="server" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DOC_ID") %>' CommandName="doc" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("FILE_NAME") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Review">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_rev"  runat="server">Review</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
</asp:GridView>
```

i need to pop up the div on "lnk_rev" click.

$("#lnk_file").live("click", function () {
         $("#modal").dialog({
             title: "jQuery Modal Dialog Popup",
             buttons: {
                 Close: function () {
                     $(this).dialog('close');
                 }
             },
             modal: true
         });
         return false;
     });

Comment: What have you tried? Popups don't just show up cause you want them. jqueryui is very well documented, and all common problems related to asp.net and jqueryui are covered on this site already.

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening is the gridview control is renaming your linkbutton's ID when it renders on the client.  Inspect the element in your browser with the tool of your choice and confirm that you're wiring your click event-handler up to elements that actually exist.